# Variable de SESSION para un formulario

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito impedir que el filtro asignado se pierda al paginar, modificar, eliminar y/o buscar registros. Este es uno de los 3 input que tengo asignados a una tabla en sql, los tres comparten el `$result`.

¿Cómo agrego la variable `$SESSION` a este ejercicio?

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    Filtrar por región: 
    <select name="examen1">
        <option>Elija una región ...</option>
        <option value="15">XV Región de Arica y Parinacota</option>
        <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['region']) and $_POST['region'] == 1):?> selected <?php endif;?>>I Región de Tarapacá</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['region']) and $_POST['region'] == 2):?> selected <?php endif;?>>II Región de Antofagasta</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['region']) and $_POST['region'] == 3):?> selected <?php endif;?>>III Región de Atacama</option>
        <option value="4" <?php if(isset($_POST['region']) and $_POST['region'] == 4):?> selected <?php endif;?>>IV Región de Coquimbo</option>
        <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['region']) and $_POST['region'] == 5):?> selected <?php endif;?>>V Región de Valparaíso</option>
        <option value="13" <?php if(isset($_POST['region']) and $_POST['region'] == 13):?> selected <?php endif;?>>RM de Santiago</option>
        <option value="6" <?php if(isset($_POST['region']) and $_POST['region'] == 6):?> selected <?php endif;?>>VI Región de O´Higgins</option>
        <option value="7" <?php if(isset($_POST['region']) and $_POST['region'] == 7):?> selected <?php endif;?>>VII Región del Maule</option>
        <option value="8" <?php if(isset($_POST['region']) and $_POST['region'] == 8):?> selected <?php endif;?>>VIII Región del Biobío</option>
        <option value="9" <?php if(isset($_POST['region']) and $_POST['region'] == 9):?> selected <?php endif;?>>IX Región de La Araucanía</option>
        <option value="14" <?php if(isset($_POST['region']) and $_POST['region'] == 14):?> selected <?php endif;?>>XIV Región de Los Ríos</option>
        <option value="10" <?php if(isset($_POST['region']) and $_POST['region'] == 10):?> selected <?php endif;?>>X Región de Los Lagos</option>
        <option value="11" <?php if(isset($_POST['region']) and $_POST['region'] == 11):?> selected <?php endif;?>>XI Región de Aysén</option>
        <option value="12" <?php if(isset($_POST['region']) and $_POST['region'] == 12):?> selected <?php endif;?>>XII Región de Magallanes</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
</form>

<?php 
if (isset($_GET['examen1'])) {
    $PorRegion = ($_GET['examen1']);
    $examen1 = $PorRegion;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM comunas WHERE region = $PorRegion");
}
?>
```

Comment: Tu quieres guardar en la variable $_SESSION el resultado de la consulta mysql?

Comment: A ver si entiendo, ¿lo que quieres saber cómo guardar el valor del filtro elegido por el cliente desde el navegador y luego recuperar dicho valor al armar el listado de opciones? ¿Tienes resuelto lo primero o sabes como hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas la variable sesion, en tu primera linea agregas esto:

```
<?php 
$_GET['region'] = (isset($_GET['examen1']))?$_GET['examen1']:'';
?>
```

tambien reemplaza todos los _POST por _GET, fijate que en tu FORM los datos los envías con el method GET

RESULTADO:

```
<?php 
$_GET['region'] = (isset($_GET['examen1']))?$_GET['examen1']:'';
?>
<form action="" method="GET">
        Filtrar por región: 
        <select name="examen1">
            <option>Elija una región ...</option>
            <option value="15">XV Región de Arica y Parinacota</option>
            <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_GET['region']) and $_GET['region'] == 1):?> selected <?php endif;?>>I Región de Tarapacá</option>
            <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_GET['region']) and $_GET['region'] == 2):?> selected <?php endif;?>>II Región de Antofagasta</option>
            <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_GET['region']) and $_GET['region'] == 3):?> selected <?php endif;?>>III Región de Atacama</option>
            <option value="4" <?php if(isset($_GET['region']) and $_GET['region'] == 4):?> selected <?php endif;?>>IV Región de Coquimbo</option>
            <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_GET['region']) and $_GET['region'] == 5):?> selected <?php endif;?>>V Región de Valparaíso</option>
            <option value="13" <?php if(isset($_GET['region']) and $_GET['region'] == 13):?> selected <?php endif;?>>RM de Santiago</option>
            <option value="6" <?php if(isset($_GET['region']) and $_GET['region'] == 6):?> selected <?php endif;?>>VI Región de O´Higgins</option>
            <option value="7" <?php if(isset($_GET['region']) and $_GET['region'] == 7):?> selected <?php endif;?>>VII Región del Maule</option>
            <option value="8" <?php if(isset($_GET['region']) and $_GET['region'] == 8):?> selected <?php endif;?>>VIII Región del Biobío</option>
            <option value="9" <?php if(isset($_GET['region']) and $_GET['region'] == 9):?> selected <?php endif;?>>IX Región de La Araucanía</option>
            <option value="14" <?php if(isset($_GET['region']) and $_GET['region'] == 14):?> selected <?php endif;?>>XIV Región de Los Ríos</option>
            <option value="10" <?php if(isset($_GET['region']) and $_GET['region'] == 10):?> selected <?php endif;?>>X Región de Los Lagos</option>
            <option value="11" <?php if(isset($_GET['region']) and $_GET['region'] == 11):?> selected <?php endif;?>>XI Región de Aysén</option>
            <option value="12" <?php if(isset($_GET['region']) and $_GET['region'] == 12):?> selected <?php endif;?>>XII Región de Magallanes</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Pero, necesito agregar las variables de SQL para delimitar mi consulta. En ese caso cómo seria?

Answer (score 0):

si quieres guardar sólo el resultado te quedaría una cosa así:

```
 <?php 
        if (isset($_GET['examen1'])) {
            $PorRegion = ($_GET['examen1']);
            $examen1 = $PorRegion;
            $_SESSION['examen1']=$examen1;
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM comunas WHERE region = $PorRegion");
        } 

    ?>
```

O puedes probar con [sessionStorage](http://www.aprenderaprogramar.es/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=888:sessionstorage-y-localstorage-javascript-diferencias-guardar-datos-en-cache-y-persistencia-cu01198e&catid=78:tutorial-basico-programador-web-javascript-desde-&Itemid=206)

Resumen de métodos y propiedades de sessionStorage:

- sessionStorage.setItem('clave', 'valor');
  Guarda la información valor a la que se podrá acceder invocando a clave. Por ejemplo clave puede ser nombre y valor puede ser Francisco.
- `sessionStorage.getItem('clave')`
  Recupera el value de la clave especificada. Por ejemplo si clave es nombre puede recuperar “Francisco”.
- sessionStorage[clave]=valor
  Igual que setItem

  etc...

[php](/questions/tagged/php)[sql](/questions/tagged/sql)

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero aún asi no guarda la información. Sera necesario declarar el `$SESSION`por ejemplo en un `if (isset($_SESSION['examen1'] != "")` ?

Comment: Lo has provado con un echo $_SESSION['examen1'] para ver si se guarda o no? En teoría lo que dices tu no hace falta.

Comment: Si, y me imprime el indice del filtro (ej: 5 => valparaiso) , pero no me imprime el resultado, por eso en un momento pense en sesionar el $result :/

Comment: Incluso haciendo el print_r()?

Answer (score 0):

La forma de almacenar datos en `$_SESSION` es:

1. Inicializar la sesión con `session_start()`
2. Leer/establecer datos con `$_SESSION['nombreLlave']`

En tu caso, podrías establecerlo antes de tu condición:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['examen1'])) {
    $_SESSION['examen1'] = $_GET['examen1'];
}

if (isset($_SESSION['examen1'])) {
    $PorRegion = $_SESSION['examen1'];
    $examen1 = $PorRegion;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM comunas WHERE region = $PorRegion");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Pero aún sigue sin guardar mis cambios :/

Answer (score 0):

Al principio de la página debes definir las variables de sesión.

```
<?php
session_start();
$seleccion=""
if (isset($_GET['examen1'])) {
    $_SESSION['examen1'] = $_GET['examen1'];
    $seleccion= $_SESSION['examen1'];
}
?>
```

Luego el en select, deberías cambiar los `option` por algo similar a esto

```
<option value="1" <?php if ($condicion == 1):?> selected <?php endif;?>>I Región de Tarapacá</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

veo que en un sitio le llamas examen1 y en otras PorRegion, deberías llamarle igual, por ejemplo examen1. Además, en unos casos utilizas GET y en otros POST, utiliza por ejemplo GET:

```
//Función que devuelve un valor que está guardada en SESSION o se envía por GET
function getValue($name){

    //Asignamos la variable $value a través de la sesión si existe
    $value = (isset($_SESSION[$name])? $_SESSION[$name] : null);

    //Si se envía por GET, capturamos la variable y la guardamos en sesión
    if (isset($_GET[$name])) {
        $value = $_GET[$name];
        $_SESSION[$name]= $value ;
    }
    return $value;
}


//Asignamos un array vació a $result por si no hay resultados
$result = array();
$examen1 = getValue('examen1');


//Si tenemos la variable, sea por SESSION y por GET, hacemos la consulta
if($examen1){
  $result = mysqli_query(
        $conn, 
       "SELECT * FROM comunas WHERE region = $examen1"
  );
}
```

Además, el html lo podrías tener así:

```
    <?php $examen1 = getValue('examen1'); ?>
    <form action="" method="GET">
    Filtrar por región: 
    <select name="examen1">
        <option>Elija una región ...</option>
        <option value="15" <?php if($examen1 == 15):?> selected <?php endif;?>>XV Región de Arica y Parinacota</option>
        <option value="1" <?php if($examen1 == 1):?> selected <?php endif;?>>I Región de Tarapacá</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if($examen1 == 2):?> selected <?php endif;?>>II Región de Antofagasta</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if($examen1 == 3):?> selected <?php endif;?>>III Región de Atacama</option>
        <option value="4" <?php if($examen1 == 4):?> selected <?php endif;?>>IV Región de Coquimbo</option>
        <option value="5" <?php if($examen1 == 5):?> selected <?php endif;?>>V Región de Valparaíso</option>
        <option value="13" <?php if($examen1 == 13):?> selected <?php endif;?>>RM de Santiago</option>
        <option value="6" <?php if($examen1 == 6):?> selected <?php endif;?>>VI Región de O´Higgins</option>
        <option value="7" <?php if($examen1 == 7):?> selected <?php endif;?>>VII Región del Maule</option>
        <option value="8" <?php if($examen1 == 8):?> selected <?php endif;?>>VIII Región del Biobío</option>
        <option value="9" <?php if($examen1 == 9):?> selected <?php endif;?>>IX Región de La Araucanía</option>
        <option value="14" <?php if($examen1 == 14):?> selected <?php endif;?>>XIV Región de Los Ríos</option>
        <option value="10" <?php if($examen1 == 10):?> selected <?php endif;?>>X Región de Los Lagos</option>
        <option value="11" <?php if($examen1 == 11):?> selected <?php endif;?>>XI Región de Aysén</option>
        <option value="12" <?php if($examen1 == 12):?> selected <?php endif;?>>XII Región de Magallanes</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
</form>
```

Por último, recuerda que para utilizar sesiones debes tener la sesión creada:

```
session_start();
```